# how can I loop over data serialized by jQuery and then populate a div?

Tags: jquery, serialization, deserialization, each

I have the following serialized data string (Some of the contents are from checkboxes so that is why the 'brand' is repeated) coming from another page:

`brand=Ford&brand=Dodge&brand=Mazda&year=2013&type=compact`

and I would like to populate the div tag with the id of "results":

```
<div id="results">    
    <div id="brand"></div>    
    <div id="year"></div>    
    <div id="type"></div>    
</div>
```

I'm currently using this code to loop over the data:

```
$.each(SelectionData.split('&'), function (index, elem) {    
    var vals = elem.split('=');    
    $('#' + vals[0]).text(decodeURIComponent(vals[1].replace(/\+/g, ' ')));    
});
```

It has been working fine until we added checkboxes to the form.  Now I'm only able to display the last value in a string when the names are the same as show here:

**This is what we have now**

```
<div id="results">
    <div id="brand">Mazda</div>    
    <div id="year">2013</div>    
    <div id="type">compact</div>    
</div>
```

**This is what we are looking for:**

```
<div id="results">
    <div id="brand">Ford,Dodge,Mazda</div>    
    <div id="year">2013</div>    
    <div id="type">compact</div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand why you want the result to be formatted inside a div called `results` but your code attempts to change the text of a element with an id equaliing the name of the uri paramter name.

Anyway I think I've figured out what you want to do.  [Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/ixogax/2/edit)

The HTML:

```
<div id="brand"></div>
<div id="year"></div>
<div id="type"></div>
```

The Code:

```
var SelectionData = 'brand=Ford&brand=Dodge&brand=Mazda&year=2013&type=compact';

$.each(SelectionData.split('&'), function (index, elem) {
    var vals = elem.split('=');
    var $div = $("#"+vals[0]);
    var separator = '';
    if ($div.html().length > 0) {
        separator = ', ';
    }
    $div.html($div.html() + separator + decodeURIComponent(vals[1].replace(/\+/g, '  ')));
});
```

Comment: As for the "why" behind it, the client is asking to display the users selection to the screen before continuing on to the next page.

Comment: Nice touch with the space after the ',' separator = ', ';

Comment: @dlackey Thats fine, but what I noticed is your code tries to change the text of an element called `#brand` or `#year` but the result you want is just contained within an element called `#results`.

Comment: Oh nice, catch!  I entered the SO question and before posting made some changes in my source code and didn't revise the SO question.  I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly!  Especially nice job since my code wasn't clear (code has been revised for future onlookers).